# How to hold data without change in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a user info object like this

```
data: function(){
  return {
    userinfo: {
       name:'',
       username:'',
       imagePath:''
   },
    previousUserInfo:{}
  }
 }
```

and somewhere else i display this user infos:

```
<template>
  <div> user name: {{userinfo.name}}</div>
  <div> username: {{userinfo.username}}</div>
                  ....
```

in some situation current user changes and i should save previous user data in previousUserInfo object:

```
 this.$set(this, 'previousUserInfo', this.userinfo);
```

but  when user fills new data in userinfo, previousUserInfo data also changes.

i also tried to user another variable to hold data but reuslts is the same :

```
var previousUserInfo = this.userinfo;
this.$set(this, 'previousUserInfo', previousUserInfo);
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.userinfo` and `this.previousUserInfo` are pointing to same object.

You can try doing deep copy value of `this.userinfo`

```
 this.$set(this, 'previousUserInfo', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.userinfo));
```